# Passing FormGroup as input directive to child component but set inside of subscribe in parent

Tags: angular, typescript

OK I am pulling my hair out with this.

I have my parent component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Guest } from "../models/guest.interface";
import { GuestService } from "../services/guest.service";
import { ActivatedRoute } from "@angular/router";
import { FormControl, FormGroup, FormArray } from '@angular/forms';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
import { GuestFormMapper } from "app/guests/services/guest-form.mapper";

@Component({
    template: `    
        <h1>Guest Viewer</h1>  

        <form [formGroup]="form" novalidate>
            <guest-detail [parent]="form"></guest-detail>
        </form>
`
})
export class GuestViewerComponent implements OnInit {
    form: FormGroup;
    guest: Guest;

    constructor(private guestService: GuestService,
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private guestFormMapper: GuestFormMapper) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        let id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];

        if (id) {
            this.route.params
                .switchMap((data: Guest) => this.guestService.get(data.id))
                .subscribe((guest: Guest) => {
                    if (guest) {
                        this.form = this.guestFormMapper.mapToForm(guest);
                    } else {
                        //todo
                    }
                });
        } else {
            this.form = this.guestFormMapper.mapToForm(new Guest());
        }
    }
}
```

I have the form:FormGroup but it doesn't get given a value until I have hit my api.

The problem I am having is that in my child component I then get:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.
```

My child component is currently pretty simple:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Guest } from "../models/guest.interface";
import {FormControl, FormGroup, FormArray} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    selector: 'guest-detail',
    templateUrl:'guest-detail.component.html',
})
export class GuestDetailComponent {
    @Input()
    parent: FormGroup;
}
```

and then the html:

```
<div class="panel-body" [formGroup]="parent">
    <div formGroupName="guest">
        <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-sm-6">
            <label>First Name*  </label>
            <input formControlName="firstname" type="text" class="form-control input-sm">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What is the best way to go about achieving this?

I'll need to re-use the guest-detail form as part of other forms moving forward hence splitting it out like this.

Comment: Why not just add an *ngIf="form" to your template?

Comment: I don't believe it. I was trying that in the child component... not the parent!